# converting data returned by a sql query in C# into row-wise and column-wise string data

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I am using .net 3.5 . I have a database on which i want to run queries. I am using data adapters or SqlCommand to run the query. But eventually I want the data in row-wise and column-wise string data. What is the way to do that ?
I mean how to extract the data in this way from the dataset(whuich is what is returned by sqlDataAdapter) ? Or is there some other approach to this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into the [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) class.

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(
    queryString, connection);
adapter.Fill(dataset);
```

You access values by method of:

```
DataSet.Tables["tableName"].Rows[rowIndex]["columnName"]
```

Or alternatively:

```
foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            //Do something with
            row[column];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could go the cheap way and use foreach to iterate through the Rows in the specified Table in the DataSet.

foreach(DataRow myRow in myDataSet.Tables[n].Rows) { ... }

Edit: Must have been typing this at the same time as the other guy :) You wanted string data. You'll probably have to use myRow[columnIndex].ToString() since it will be an Object type of some sort.

Also, if you just need one string from the database, may I suggest you write a query that does the concatenation server-side, and a wrapper function that gets myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString();